# Ubuntu 14.04 and tcsh

Tags: tcsh

I've tried the recommended method to install the TCSH shell in Ubuntu 14.04,

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

but get the message:

```
Unable to locate package tcsh
```

Is there something else I need to download?

Comment: Have you run sudo apt-get update before trying to install tcsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my system:

```
[romano:~] % apt-cache policy tcsh 
tcsh:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6.18.01-2
  Version table:
     6.18.01-2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

...so you need to have "universe" enabled. You can check this by choosing "Software and Updates" in the dash and:

[image]